# How to call asmx web service in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I have to develop a component in .NET to call asmx service(which has user name and password) to send sms. How can i call web service ?

Comment: tel:800.421.6897 (The company formerly known as Web Service Company)

Comment: from where you want to call the web service?

Comment: Just Consume the web service using web / service reference in visual studio and work with proxy created in C# . It shall have provision to provide Authentication details at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You have to add web reference into your application. Also add a key config for the webservice url and call the same in reference.cs of web proxy class. It will be helpful whenever url of webservice gets change.

Comment: I tried but to add it web reference but it says an error occurred while attempting to find service. but when i tried on browser it goes to login page and when i type credentials it goes to the indbox pge.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a service reference of the asmx web service you want to call to your project and create an object out of the service and call the method.